# Gimp — leave image window on top

Tags: gimp

I'd like to convince Gimp not to mess with the z-order of its windows.  Me and the window manager are perfectly able to raise a window as I want.

In particular, I'd like to sometimes have the image window on top but Gimp invariably forces the image window to stay below ALL its other windows.

---

<sup>Please note that **I don't want a single window**, I want separate windows for the different elements of the interface, that I can place where I want.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Edit>Preferences>Window management>Hints for docks and toolbox` gives your three choices:

- `Normal window`: plain windows (can be minimized, etc...)
- `Utility window`: like plain windows, but no "Minimize" button, have to use [Tab] to hide.
- `Keep above`: keep these windows above the image window

So you would be currently using the third setting.

See [the doc](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-pimping.html#gimp-prefs-window-management)